# Substituting $\Sigma_1^{(n)}$ functions into $\Sigma_1^{(n)}$ formulae

Tags: logic, set-theory

Although my question is very short, I feel the obligation to introduce the relevant notation first:

Let $M = (J_\alpha^A,B)$ be an acceptable $J$-structure with $n$-th projectum $\rho^n$ (where $\rho^0 = \alpha$) and let $H^n = H_{\omega\rho^n}^M = \{ x \in J_\alpha^A \mid M \models \operatorname{card}(\operatorname{trcl}(x)) < \omega \rho^n \}$ be the universe of the $n$-th reduct. (Note that we include successor ordinals in the indexing of the $J$-hierarchy and thus $J_\alpha^A \cap \operatorname{On} = \omega \alpha$.)

Let $\mathcal L^*$ be a language with variables $v^j_i$, $i,j < \omega$ (which are intended to range over $H^j$), $\dot \in$, $\dot =$ $\dot A$, $\dot B$ (with their obvious interpretations). Let $\Sigma_0^{(n)}$, for $n < \omega$, be the closure of all formulas $\dot A(v^j_i)$, $\dot B(v^j_i)$, $v^j_i \dot \in v^{j'}_{i'}$, $v^j_i \dot = v^{j'}_{i'}$ and $\Sigma_1^{(m)}$ formulas, for $m < n$, under $\wedge,\vee,\neg$ and bounded quantification, i.e. if $\phi$ is $\Sigma_0^{(n)}$ then $\exists v^n_i \dot \in v^m_{i'} \phi$ and $\forall v^n_i \dot \in v^m_{i'} \phi$ are $\Sigma_0^{(n)}$ for all $n \le m < \omega$.

Finally, for $0 < k < \omega$ let $\Sigma_k^{(n)}$ be the set of all formulas $\exists v_{i_1}^n \forall v_{i_2}^n \ldots Q v_{i_k}^n \phi$, where $Q$ is $\forall$ iff $n$ is even, $\exists$ otherwise and $\phi$ is in $\Sigma_{0}^{(n)}$.

We say that a relation $R(v^{j_1}_{i_1}, \ldots, v^{j_l}_{i_l})$ is $\Sigma_k^{(n)}(M)$ of type $(j_1, \ldots, j_l)$ in some parameter $p \in ^{< \omega} M$ iff there is a $\Sigma_{k}^{(n)}$ formula $\phi(v^{j_1}_{i_1}, \ldots, v^{j_l}_{i_l})$ such that for all $x_1 \in H^{j_1}, \ldots, x_l \in H^{j_l}$:
$$
R(x_1, \ldots, x_l) \Leftrightarrow M \models \phi(x_1, \ldots, x_l,p)
$$

We say that $f(v^{j_1}_{i_1}, \ldots, v^{j_l}_{i_l})$ is a $\Sigma_k^{(n)}(m)$ function to $H^j$ in some parameter $p \in ^{< \omega}M$ iff $f(v^{j_1}_{i_1}, \ldots, v^{j_l}_{i_l}) = v^j_{i_{l+1}}$ is a $\Sigma_k^{(n)}(M)$ relation of type $(j_1, \ldots, j_l, j)$ in the parameter $p$.

**Question**

Is there a simple example of a $\Sigma_1^{(n)}(M)$ function $f$ and a $\Sigma_1^{(n)}(M)$ relation $R$ such that substituting $f$ into $R$ doesn't yield a $\Sigma_1^{(n)}(M)$ relation - motivating the introduction of *good* $\Sigma_k^{(n)}(M)$ formulae?

Comment: First sentence, second paragraph, I think you meant to say $v^j_i$ are intended to range over $H^j$ instead of $H^i$. If I remember correctly, the motivation is that the $\Sigma^{(n)}_1(M)$-relations are not just graphs, they contains info about types for the reducts also. To characterize $\Sigma^{(n)}_1(M)$-relations in terms of graphs, we must use good functions and not just $\Sigma^{(n)}_1(M)$ functions alone. There will be a uniform way to describe the $\Sigma^{(n)}_1(M)$ relation resulting from a subsitution of a good $\Sigma^{(n)}_1(M)$ functionin a $\Sigma^{(n)}_1(M)$ relation $R$....

Comment: ...then using the scheme generating the good functions and an induction one can show that the substitution of a $\Sigma^{(n)}_1(M)$-relations using good $\Sigma^{(n)}_1(M)$ function are uniformly $\Sigma^{(n)}_1(M)$.

Comment: @Carlo Well, yes. I'm aware of "good $\Sigma_1^{(n)}(M)$ functions" and I see how substituting them into $\Sigma_1^{(n)}(M)$ relations yields (uniformly in the definition of the relation and the functions) a $\Sigma_1^{(n)}(M)$ relation. However, this doesn't answer my question. I'd like to see an example as how to disrupt a $\Sigma_1^{(n)}(M)$ relation by substituting a $\Sigma_1^{(n)}(M)$ function that necessarily isn't "good". A promising candidate for such a function would be a $\Sigma_1^{(n)}(M)$ function to $H^i$ for some $i < n$ that isn't $\Sigma_1^{(i)}(M)$.

Comment: @Caro Btw. Thanks for spotting my typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you substitute a variable $u^j$ in a $\Sigma_1^{(n)}$ relation by $f(v^{j_1}_{i_1}, \ldots, v^{j_l}_{i_l})$, where $f$ is a $\Sigma_1^{(n)}$ function to $H^j$, the resulting formula will take the form 
$$\exists w^j (\text{some }\Sigma_1^{(n)} \text{ formula}).$$
$j$ could be bigger than $n$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Replacing every (bounded) quantifier $Q x^n$ in a $\Sigma_1^{(n)}$ formula $\phi$ by $Q x^{n-1}$ and substituting the $\Sigma_{1}^{(n-1)}$ function $f(x^n)$ defined by $\exists x^{n-1} \colon x^n = x^{n-1}$ into this formula defines the same set as $\phi$. If $\phi$ witnesses $\rho^{n} > \rho^{n+1}$ - by defining a new subset of $\omega \rho^n$ -, we see that this substitution cannot result in a $\Sigma_1^{(n-1)}$ formula.